# Coloring of "Related" and "Hot Network Questions" are opposite standard link coloring

Tags: discussion, bug, user-interface, design

I've been browsing around StackExchange for a few hours, and every time I pass through the Mathematics StackExchange the fact that the "visited" links and normal links are displayed in the reverse of standard colors in the side bar always trips me up. Most websites use a slightly darker color for visited links, but the sidebar uses a brighter color for the visited links than for the standard links. Is there any good reason to break convention like this?

Comment: Yes, designers are mean and enjoy tripping you up.

Comment: Unfortunately people get used even to bad solutions Even if this is rectified many would claim current colors are better

Comment: I don't know that what you describe is the convention at all. The HTML default is purple for visited and blue for non-visited - nothing to do with dark and light. Off the top of my head I can't think of anywhere that specifically uses a darker color for visited.

Comment: @JackM Unstyled browser-default colors are rarely seen on professionally designed sites. Every Stack Exchange site, except this one, uses a darker shade for visited links. See also [this answer on UX](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/23596/56951).

Comment: @2mkgz That UX question is complaining about the opposite problem as this question.